# Determining the number of days in a month

Tags: datetime, vba, excel

Overall logic: determine number of days in a month. Loop through table (`wsUploadTable`) and increment value if condition is met. Loop to next day in month and repeat.

For example: 10/1/2016, loops through table for date match and increment value. Next date, 10/2/2016 loop table for match... until last day of month 10/31/2016, loop table, find match and increment value.

```
'Determine DaysinMonth and assign DaysinMonth_Distro value
DaysInMonth = DateSerial(dtTrickle_Year, dtTrickle_Month + 1, 1) - _
              DateSerial(dtTrickle_Year, dtTrickle_Month, 1)
DoM_Distro = 1 / DaysInMonth

ReDim Days(1 To DaysInMonth)
For i = 1 To DaysInMonth
    Days(i) = DateSerial(dtTrickle_Year, dtTrickle_Month, i)

  'loop table and increment cell value if condition is met

    With wsUploadTable
    lngER_PrimaryID = .Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For intPrimaryID = 2 To lngER_PrimaryID
            'store current cell value
            dblLeadsValue = .Cells(intPrimaryID, col_Upload_Leads)
            'match UploadTable row on user input and increment new value 
              If.Cells(intPrimaryID, 3).Value = Days(i) Then
              .Cells(intPrimaryID, 11).Value = dblLeadsValue + DoM_Distro
            End If
        Next 'Next PrimaryID
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! You've described your code well, but the code itself could use a bit more context; it would be nice to include the declarations for the variables you're using, and perhaps the procedure's signature as well (i.e. everything between `Sub/Function` and `End Sub/Function` - you see right now I'm not even sure I'm looking at a `Sub` or a `Function`, whether the involved variables are local or module-level, whether they're declared at all, and/or what else is in the same scope.

Answer (score 2):

Well havent tried either Excel or VBA , but the logic will go like this ,

- Loop through the table
- Say the date is day/month/year , where day,month and year are variables
- lets have an array of months which is [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
- if year is divisible by 4 or 400 , then `months[1]= months[1] + 1`
- now just display months[month]

Here `months` is the array and `month` is the number of month present in the date , for more info in arrays for VBA you can look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_arrays.htm) .

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to remove 1st of next month from 1st of this month to get the number of days.

Day 0 in the `DateSerial` function is the last day of the previous month, so this will work:

```
DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(dtTrickle_Year, dtTrickle_Month + 1, 0))
```

It's leap-year sensitive to:
`Day(DateSerial(2015, 2+ 1, 0))` returns 28.
`Day(DateSerial(2016, 2+ 1, 0))` returns 29.

Looking further through your code I've made an attempt at coding what I think you're trying to do.
I've had to add some test values and variable declarations to make it work.  It removes one of your loops by using the `FIND` method to go straight to the required cell.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim DaysInMonth As Long
    Dim DoM_Distro As Long
    Dim dtTrickle_Year As Long
    Dim dtTrickle_Month As Long
    Dim dblLeadsValue As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dtCurrentDay As Date
    Dim rFound As Range

    dtTrickle_Year = 2016
    dtTrickle_Month = 2
    dblLeadsValue = 10

    'Determine DaysinMonth and assign DaysinMonth_Distro value
    DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(dtTrickle_Year, dtTrickle_Month + 1, 0))
    DoM_Distro = 1 / DaysInMonth

    'Cycle through each day in the month.
    For i = 1 To DaysInMonth
        dtCurrentDay = DateSerial(dtTrickle_Year, dtTrickle_Month, i)

        'Seach column 2 of the table to find the date value.
        With Range("wsUploadTable").Columns(2)
            'Find the value in the table.
            Set rFound = .Find( _
                What:=dtCurrentDay, _
                After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole)

            'Providing a value is found....
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                'Place our result 10 columns to the right of the found cell.
                rFound.Offset(, 10).Value = dblLeadsValue + DoM_Distro
            End If
            Set rFound = Nothing
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```